# MVC Project and MVC project with API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have recently started working on MVC application. However my first plan was to create two separate projects in the same solution. One asp.net MVC web application and second is asp.net WebAPI. So that my Web Application will talk to Web API which in return will send JSON response to application which will be converted to View Model for View.

**Workflow Diagram :**

[image]

As i studied more i got to know that API controller and controller both merged into a single controller class in MVC 5. so here is my question how can i achieve the above workflow in **MVC 5**.

**MVC 5 Workflow Diagram**

[image]

So here comes the problem for me in MVC 5 or i am unable to understand it completely E.g :

**UserModel**

```
  public class UserModel
  {
    Public int UserId {get;set;}
    Public string Username {get;set;}
  }
```

**UserController**

```
   [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetUser(int id)
   {
      // do some work
      return View(userObject);
   }
```

**View**

```
   @model UserModel
   <h1>@Model.Username</h1>
```

but when i call the above method from mobile it will give me the rendered html which is not useful for me so do i need to create another method in the same controller in which will return data in JSON.

```
   [HttpGet()]
   public IActionResult ApiGetUser(int id)
   {
      // do some work
      return JSONResponse.. ;
   }
```

Modifying method :

```
[HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetUser(int id)
   {
      // calling api get user method
         ApiGetUser(int id); // return json
      // do some work to convert json into ModelObject
       return View(userObject);
   }
```

And if any one mobile app needs data it can call m **APIGetUser** Method but in this scenario for me its tedious and no of extra methods will be added in the same class. So my basic question is my understanding towards the flow is wrong or am i missing somethings because if below mentioned workflow is right than i would prefer the first one as its separate WebAPI project and easy to maintain ?

Comment: Do you need MVC? If building for mobile app's you can just use WeApi no need for mvc and razor.

Comment: sir i have application which will work on both mobile based and web based

Comment: I mean mobile based as in mobile app, as in hybrid-mobile app, as in building using Cordova or Secha , ionic, etc...

Comment: Anyway in your first diagram you have used web api for returning json. Your mvc controller can return json.

Comment: The thing you need to figure out / decide is; Is the API the core of your functionality. If you want your MVC application to always use the (Web)API - then I'd say you should split them and let your MVC request from your API, because it means you'll be able to change MVC implementation without affecting your API implementation. Separation of concern and all that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion both diagram are architecturally correct.

But you should consider *SRP* and *separation of concern* this: if MVC controller + WebApi controller are both an entry point to your application, running the same code and returning it in 2 different way, they are actually doing 2 different things isn'it? One serve the view and the other one the json.

Plus if you have to render a view there are naturally some behaviuour that isn't common with your web api (cache or rendering partial view for example).

If you think the same, you should leave aside that in MVC 5 both MVC+WebApi controller are under the same class and split it for the reason above.

Hope it helps!